# cURL to PHP cURL (html2pdf.raph.site)

Tags: php, curl

I found this API for converting HTML to PDF. It's working great, and it's the only free API I was able to find.
Unfortunately for me, there is only an option to use cURL but have no knowledge with cURL. I want to make a simple "html to pdf" PHP script and I hope I can use this API.

This is the cURL code:

`curl -F "file=@/path/to/file.html" \
   http://html2pdf.raph.site/`

Is there a way to integrate this code in PHP script?

Here is the API link:
http://html2pdf.raph.site/

Thank you guys!

Comment: you can use curl extension of php

Comment: any way there are dozens of libraries which does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `curl` library in PHP.

Understanding the command. From `man curl`:

> -F, --form <name=content>
>
> (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button.
>
> This enables uploading of binary files  etc.  To  force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign...
>
> The @ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload.

In PHP version earlier than 5.5 you could simply post the params like:

```
curl_set_opt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file' => '@/path/to/file.html',
]);
```

But this is no longer supported in newer versions. You will have to use [curl_file_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php) instead.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$api_url = 'http://html2pdf.raph.site';
$html_file = '/home/ally/Desktop/file.html';

$params = [
  'file' => curl_file_create($html_file),
];

$options = [
  CURLOPT_URL => $api_url,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
];

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response_body = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_error_no = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error_msg = curl_error($ch);

if ($curl_error_no) {
  print_r([
    'error_no' => $curl_error_no,
    'error_msg' => $curl_error_msg,
  ]);
  echo 'There was an error posting html to the api.' . PHP_EOL;
  die();
}
$response_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r([
  'request_url' => $api_url,
  'request_params' => $params,
  'response_code' => $response_info['http_code'],
  'response_info' => $response_info,
  'response_body' => $response_body,
]);
```

Example of my output:

```
Array
(
    [request_url] => http://html2pdf.raph.site
    [request_params] => Array
        (
            [file] => CURLFile Object
                (
                    [name] => /home/ally/Desktop/file.html
                    [mime] => 
                    [postname] => 
                )

        )

    [response_code] => 200
    [response_info] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://html2pdf.raph.site/
            [content_type] => text/plain
            [http_code] => 200
            [header_size] => 182
            [request_size] => 187
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 0.906493
            [namelookup_time] => 0.512727
            [connect_time] => 0.746585
            [pretransfer_time] => 0.747354
            [size_upload] => 236
            [size_download] => 74
            [speed_download] => 81
            [speed_upload] => 260
            [download_content_length] => 74
            [upload_content_length] => 236
            [starttransfer_time] => 0.782345
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [redirect_url] => 
            [primary_ip] => 46.101.147.77
            [certinfo] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_port] => 80
            [local_ip] => 192.168.0.10
            [local_port] => 53286
        )

    [response_body] => http://html2pdf.raph.site/static/ffc8e3bb-c0d9-4129-b756-0d5298f51bce.pdf

)
```

Hope this helps.